# how to define a custom getter which uses fields who were defined explicitly from another interface from the same class?

Tags: c#

how to define a custom getter which uses fields who were defined explicitly from another interface from the same class ?  I am getting an object or reference is required for the non static field , method or property

here is the class:

```
double IStartingCurrency.Amount { get; set; }
double ITargetCurrency.Amount { get; set; }
string IStartingCurrency.Code { get; set; }
string ITargetCurrency.Code { get; set; }
string IStartingCurrency.Description { get; }
string ITargetCurrency.Description { get; }  

double IStartingCurrency.UnitValue 
{            
    get
    {
        return IStartingCurrency.Amount; // <-- Error here
    }
}
```

Here is the interface:

```
public interface IStartingCurrency
{
    double Amount { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; }
    double UnitValue { get; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any logic behind explicit implementation of interfaces with auto-properties? Why not just `Amount`, `Code`, `Description`? Twice less code and no problem.

Comment: Try `((IStartingCurrency) this).Amount`...

Comment: It looks like your class is trying to do too much, why not have properties for starting and target that in turn have amount/code/etc.?

Comment: Since the `UnitValue` is read-only, I think you'll need to implement that interface somewhere in order to give it a value.